# Middle div resize edge divs don't

Tags: html, css, resize

I have 1 row of 3 divs. The rows on the edges (1,3) are arrow indicators. Edge/Column 1 has an arrow indicating left; edge/column3 has an arrow indicating right. The middle column (2) is scrollable. I want for when the middle column, the edges remain intact.

In the code example. The first column remains while the middle column scroll but the third column (right arrow) disappears.

Please and thank you in advanced.

```css
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #3d85c6;
    }

    .letter-changer {
      animation: example 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
    }

    ul.mp-0,
    .mp-0 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    div.lk-shadow{
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);      
    }

    div.lk-verb-box {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 300;
      min-width: 150px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }

    div.lk-verb-border {
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .lk-scroll-arrow {
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 40px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    ul.lk-verb {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0%;
      word-spacing: 0%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: auto;
      display: block;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    li.lk-verb {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      color: #3d85c6;
      border: solid 1px #3d85c6;
      height: 20px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 7px;
      padding-right: 7px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    li.lk-verb:hover {
      background-color: #3d85c6;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .lk-fl {
      float: left;
    }

    .lk-ele-box {
      overflow-x: auto;
    }


    @keyframes example {
      from {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }

      to {
        transform: translateX(140px);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
      var el = document.getElementById("vbr10");
      el.scrollIntoView(true);
    });
```

```html
  <div class="lk-shadow" style="padding-right: 5px;">
    <div class="lk-scroll-arrow lk-fl" style="display: table-cell;">&#129172;</div>
    <div class="lk-verb-box" >
      <ul class="lk-verb mp-0 lk-fl">
        <li id="vrb1" class="lk-verb">Element 1</li>
        <li id="vrb2" class="lk-verb">Element 1</li>
        <li id="vrb3" class="lk-verb">Element 2</li>
        <li id="vrb4" class="lk-verb">Element 0</li>
        <li id="vrb5" class="lk-verb">Element 3</li>
        <li id="vrb6" class="lk-verb">Element 4</li>
        <li id="vrb7" class="lk-verb">Element 5</li>
        <li id="vrb8" class="lk-verb">Element 6</li>
        <li id="vrb9" class="lk-verb">Element 7</li>
        <li id="vrb10" class="lk-verb">Element 8</li>
        <li id="vrb11" class="lk-verb">Element 9</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="lk-scroll-arrow lk-fl" style="display: table-cell;">&#129174;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe try adding some code to your question, as it is close to impossible to help debug without it.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "I want for when the middle column, the edges remain intact." I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, or what you meant by that.